# OracleAQ loses messages?

Tags: jms, oracle-aq

After successfully sending my message, i'm just browsing for it..
But, i get only the messages which i send @ that time..That is, i don't see any previous messages which i sent to the queue.

I'm using a simple java client to send messages.
My sample code is;

```
sender.send(message);

Enumeration enu = browser.getEnumeration();
List list = new ArrayList();
 while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
  TextMessage message= (TextMessage) enu.nextElement();
   System.out.println("** " + list.size());
   list.add(message.getText());
  }
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
 System.out.println("Browsed msg " + list.get(i));
}
```

I don't use consumers here.. So , how i loose my messages from the queue? :(

I'm trying with OracleAQ..

Comment: That is my fault..One of my backend server also was listening to the same queue..